# How to render/create a Vue component after an specific event (e.g. @click @change)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2, vue-component

I'am new to Vue JS and face now a problem, which seems should be easy but I can't find a way to do it.

This is what I want to do and the reason:

- I want to first load some data from the server/local, edit the data, and show the data to the user. But which data to load is decided by the user (through buttons, e. g. click event)
- Because the way to show the data is a little bit too complicated (I mean the HTML codes, the UI), so I decided to create a global component to handle it, so my Vue instance won't be messed up.

I have alreday did a part of the component, but the problem is, every time I refresh my page, it comes the warning, said the some parameters are undefined.

Of course they are not defined at the beginning, because the user haven't choose which data to load.

Can someone with experience of that tell me. How I can tell the Vue to render a component after something like a click event?

I will try to make a simplified code example below, so you can understand that better:

**- part of the main.js file (simplified)**

```
// the global Vue component
var infoBox = Vue.component('info-box', {
    props:['infos'],
    template:`
        <div>
            <li>{{ infos.name }}</li>
            <li>{{ infos.id }}</li>
            <li>{{ infos.title }}</li>
            <li>{{ infos.whatever }}</li> // continues..also simplified, actually I need to edit the infos first
        </div>
    `
}

// the Vue instance
var app = new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        data: '',
    },
    methods: {
        loadData: function() {
            // load the needed data from the server
            this.data = $.getJSON(/*....*/) // just for example that I loaded some data and push it to the instance
            

        }
    }
})
```

**- Part of the HTML file**

```
<div id="app">
    <button @click="loadData"></button> // also simplified, the real project has different kinds of buttons, the user can decide which data should be loaded
    <info-box :infos="data"></info-box> // get the data from the Vue instance, which does not exist until the button was clicked the the data was loaded
</div>
```

**More details about my problem:**

- The workflow is actually OK, because I have alredy defined a empty "data" in the Vue instance. The real Problem is inside the component, when I want to edit and handle some data, because before the click, the data is empty, so I got a lot of the "XXX is not defined" warning because some functions I use don't allow undefined props.
- The perfect way I want: Is there any way that I can say to Vue: OK, now the button is clicked, let's see, the data is loaded, now pls render/create the component.
- If not, than the only way I can do is to load all the data first when I create the Vue instance. But obviously it's too much data and it will cause problems.
- **I have tried to understand the Vue official document "Async component", which seems to be the best solution for me:**

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

But I can't go any further because I can't understand this at all and can't use it in my project (***and I think this code is the key to tell the Vue, that he can render/create the component now***):

```
require(['./my-async-component'], resolve)
```

- Also, the **setTimeOut** is not what I wanted, because if the user don't click the button, we can wait until the world ends, the data is always empty.

Comment: `v-if` seems like the best solution for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of ways you could fix this.

You can simply set a `v-if="data"` on your component which only loads the entire component when your data is loaded. Normally I would put another element below this with `v-else` and have a loading spinner component or something alike.

If you want to have the layout of component you can do the same within the template of your `info-box` component.

```
<div>
    <div class="wrapper" v-if="infos">
        <li>{{ infos.name }}</li>
        <li>{{ infos.id }}</li>
        <li>{{ infos.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ infos.whatever }}</li>
    </div>

    <div class="spinner-loading">
        Put your loading animation here
    </div>
</div>
```

An async component will not help you because the async component might actually load before your AJAX request has actually finished. You misunderstand how async components work.

You can also created computed properties for each of your info properties and put in placeholders if they are not set so you can manage them individually. Plenty of options here but you need to make sure you have data or at least a placeholder before showing your template.